# Could not start PsExec service on remote: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: command-line, windows-registry

Here is the script I have compiled:

```
@echo off
REM This file assumes you have psexec installed
REM Ask for machine name or IP
set /p machine= Please enter the machine name or ip:
REM check for workstation online, if not exit
ping %machine% | find "Reply"
if errorlevel 1 goto :offline
if errorlevel 0 goto :install

:offline
echo Workstation not online
pause
exit

:install
xcopy "w:\*****\*****\psexec.exe" \\%machine%\c$\windows\system32
xcopy "w:\*****\*****\*****\*****\fix.reg" \\%machine%\c$\temp
PsExec -s -i \\%machine% -u domainadmin \\%machine%\c$\windows\regedit.exe -i "c:\temp\fix.reg"
pause

<< Reg file  fix.reg>>
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
```

The script is working down to the point where it has copied the files from the network to the remote computer. I then get asked for the domain admin password `PsExec` starts then I get the message:

> Could not start PsExec service on Computername: The system cannot find the file specified.

I can run the .reg file by remoting onto the computer and double clicking it but there has to be a way to get PsExec to run it remotely

```
\\%machine%\c$\temp\fix.reg psexec -s \\%machine%\c$\windows\system32\reg.exe
```

The first half of this line is working correctly, it runs the reg file but rather than updating the registry on the target computer it updates my local pc registry can anyone see the issue?

Comment: Could you post the script how it is exactly without your password info?

Comment: This is the line that seems to be causing an issue as the rest runs correctly:  PsExec -u DomainAdmin \\%machine% regedit -s "c$\temp\fix.reg"

Comment: Fixed it, I had PsExec in the wrong place, swapped it to this: \\%machine%\c$\temp\fix.reg psexec -u -p and now it works a treat :-)

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: It didn't fix it :-( Its now very confusing, %machine% is recognised all the way through the script as the machine that's typed in on line 4 but is recognised as the local machine when executing the .reg file

Comment: Rewrote my script to this:

Comment: running this line \\%remotemachine%\c$\temp\OfficeDocumentfix.reg I get a pop up box asking me if I trust the location, I select yes then I get a message to say it has updated the registry, problem is it updates my local computer registry rather than the remote computer, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
PsExec.exe -s \\%machine% -u domainadmin C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C c:\windows\system32\reg.exe IMPORT c:\temp\fix.reg
```

Comment: Can you explain why you believe that this would make a difference? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: His original code he was trying to use regedit.exe which does not support registry imports. Only reg.exe does.

Comment: (1) I believe that you’re mistaken.  [Command line options for Regedit.exe (techtarget.com)](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Command-line-options-for-Regeditexe), [RegEdit Command-Line Options (O’Reilly)](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-the-windows/1565929438/ch04s09.html) and [Regedit - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) all seem to say that `regedit` can import registry values from a `.reg` file from the command line.  (Microsoft’s documentation is unclear.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The `-i` option that the OP is trying to use does seem to be an error, though. … … P.S. I believe that, when you run a `.reg` file through Explorer (e.g., by double-clicking on it) or `cmd`, it does it by running `regedit` — see “HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\open\command”. … … (2) More importantly, the “Could not start PsExec service …” error message make it look like the OP’s attempt is failing at the PsExec level, and that he isn’t even getting `regedit` to run, so I wonder why you believe that your command will get ``cmd.exe`` to run.

Comment: Why don't you help him if you seem to know all the problems??? I've used PsExec for years, I don't have time to argue with you. The above would work based on my experience with PsExec. Could not find the file specified indicates it could not find the exe to execute... adding the full path corrects that and using the correct formatting. I've never seen any documentation on regedit importing reg files via cmd line but you get an GUI dialog option... This is not the correct way to use CLI (non-gui) tools like PsExec. REG.EXE is the correct tool to perform a command line import. Good day.

Comment: By GUI dialog I mean "are you sure you wish to import x y z reg file?"

REGEDIT was designed for GUI not CLI.